# Filter multiple columns of a tab delimited file?

Tags: bash, shell

A very simple question, How do I filter out a tab delimited file with multiple columns?

The file looks like this:

```
chr10   100008748   100010821   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   3   0   0   3   5   13  2   3   11  1   4
chr10   100010933   100011322   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   0   2   0   5   3   11  0   0   6   1   4
chr10   100010954   100011322   .   .   -   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
chr10   100011459   100012109   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   4   8   2   17  4   3   11  2   2
chr10   100011959   100015344   .   .   +   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The filter I need to apply is 10. I need to see 10 or greater in all columns to be precise. I tried the following script but it did not work:

```
cat infile.txt \
> while read line \
> do \
> ext=`echo $line | cut -f11-` \
> if [ "$ext" >= "10" \] \
> then \
> echo $line \
> fi \
> done > outfile.txt
```

What should I be doing instead?

The Error message:

```
cat: while: No such file or directory
cat: read: No such file or directory
cat: line: No such file or directory
cat: do: No such file or directory
cat: ext=: No such file or directory
cat: if: No such file or directory
cat: [: No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
cat: 10: No such file or directory
cat: ]: No such file or directory
cat: then: No such file or directory
cat: echo: No such file or directory
cat: fi: No such file or directory
cat: done: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you give a sample output?

Comment: 10 or greater in all columns or 10 or greater in any column?

Comment: 10 or greater in columns 11 through 22

Comment: Expected output ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {for (i=11;i<=NF;i++) {printf $i"\t" }}{printf "\n"}' file.txt
```

Here

```
 1. FS="\t" will set FS as tab.
 2. for loop will start from i=11
 3.  printf $i"\t" will print each value corresponding to value of i + a tab in same line(since we used printf).
 4.  and in last printf "\n" will take you to the next line for each input line.
```

sample out put will be:

```
 1       3       0       0       3       5       13      2       3       11      1       4
 1       0       2       0       5       3       11      0       0       6       1       4
 0       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
 1       1       0       4       8       2       17      4       3       11      2       2
 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F'\t' '{for (i=11; i<=22; i++) if ($i>10) {print; break}}' file
chr10   100008748   100010821   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   3   0   0   3   5   13  2   3   11  1   4
chr10   100010933   100011322   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   0   2   0   5   3   11  0   0   6   1   4
chr10   100011459   100012109   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   4   8   2   17  4   3   11  2   2
```